# Gridview result import to Opener Gridview VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have GridView and Pop-up window for lookup and for populating selected data to the Document.Opener.Gridview. But My problem is I can't transfer multiple selected items from Pop-up window to Document.Opener.Gridview. Is possible to transfer GridView data to its Opener.Gridview using ASP.Net?

Let say I have main web form then I have import button to populate data of Main web form Gridview. Once I click the import button it will pop-up a new web form dialog box on the middle of the main web form and it has also Gridview with some data. How can I transfer the pop-up web form Gridview data to the Main Web form Gridview?

Comment: What is `Document.Opener.Gridview`?

Comment: Let say I have main web form then I have import button to populate data of Main web form Gridview. Once I click the import button it will pop-up a new web form dialog box on the middle of the main web form and it has also Gridview with some data. How can I transfer the pop-up web form Gridview data to the Main Web form Gridview?